# JavaScript to Validate :Password cannot be a substring of the EmailID

Tags: javascript

I need a javascript to validate password field against emailID textBox where user types emailID

Password Validation rule : Password cannot be a substring of the EmailID Used

Example Email :alex123@yahoo.com
Example following passwords  are invalid as they are substrings of the above emailID

1. alex123 --invalid
2. alex1234 --is invalid
3. @yahoo.com ---invalid
4. passrobin --valid

Comment: Should alx123@yahoo.com be alex123@yahoo.com? Does 123 or alex pass?

Comment: Given your second example where "alex1234" is invalid, do you mean that the password cannot contain a substring that is also a substring of the email address? If so, what's the minimum substring length to test, I mean presumably you're not going to go as far as not allowing the same letters?

Answer (score 2):

```
var pass = "alex123";
var email = "alex123@yahoo.com";
var emailParts = email.split("@");
if(pass.indexOf(emailParts[0]) > -1 || pass.indexOf(emailParts[1]) > -1){
    alert("invalid");
}
```

Comment: Don't use the variable name `pass` not a good idea. Otherwise +1

Answer (score 1):

```
if ( email.indexOf( pword ) > -1 ) {
    // invalid: password is a substring of email
}
```

Comment: This is based on his validation rule: "Password cannot be a substring of the EmailID Used". That is what this checks for.

Comment: from post `2) alex1234 --is invalid` and `alex123` would not match.

Comment: The question post disagrees with itself. It says that "alex1234" is invalid because it is a substring of "alex123@yahoo.com", and obviously it isn't.